# Meta descriptions not being used in google search

Tags: wordpress, search, meta

my site is www.eatfituk.com

I am using wordpress seo (yoast) to input my meta titles and descriptions, google search takes the title but wont take the description. I have had the site for about a year a I have asked google to crawl my site many times but with no change.

I dont know if there is something in my site causing it not to work.

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 1):

Just had a look at your site, looks good!

Your Robot Meta tag is:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noodp,noydir"/>
```

I'm pretty sure this is the cause to your problem, when you use noodp which allows you to opt out of the description. More info on matt cutts [blog](https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/google-supports-meta-noodp-tag/)

Try putting them to "index, follow" instead, I'm pretty sure this will fix your problem!

Comment: Thanks! I have changed it and hopefully it will work. Just have to wait until Google crawls my site

Comment: @JoeTaylor Sounds good! If it works could you mark as the answer so I can rank up! Cheers